# Is $ \frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$ a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is $ \frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$  a polynomial?

I reviewed conjugates and exponents this afternoon when trying to rationalize the denominator.  I was wondering if this is equivalent? $$ \frac{x^2}{x^2-1} = x^2 + x^{-2} -1^{-1} $$

General polynomial equation is $$P(x) =a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2} x^{n-2} + \cdots$$

$N$ has to be a positive integer for an equation to be a polynomial.  By this definition then $\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$ is not a polynomial.

Conjugates up to this point have only been used for fractions with radicals or imaginary numbers in the denominator. However I was struggling with how to rationalize the denominator when I was studying this problem.

Comment: $ \dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1} = x^2 + x^{-2} -1^{-1} $ is wrong and $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1}$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: For that matter, $x^2+x^{-2}-1$ is not a polynomial either. It's a [Laurent polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) -- but that doesn't mean a polynomial with extra properties, but a _generalization_ of "polynomial" that shares some but not all of its properties.

Comment: Personally, I have seen the expression *rational function* to describe an expression like $\frac{x^2}{x^2 - 1}$.  It is unclear to me how ambiguous the expression *rational function* is.  That is, it is unclear to me whether it automatically implies that the numerator and denominator are both polynomials.

Comment: @user2661923: "Rational function" is a common term with a well-agreed meaning, and $\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$ is indeed an example of one. It does require the numerator and denominator to be polynomials. A different but equivalent definition says that a rational function is any function that can be written down using some combination of constants and the four basic arithmetic operations, and which avoids division by zero for at least some values of the variable.

Comment: If you want to simplify the rational function, you would get $$\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}=1+\frac1{x^2-1}=1+\frac12\left(\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}\right)$$

Comment: Why can’t negative exponents be used?  I also should do some more research on ration functions and rational numbers.  I thought the difference is a ration number and an irrational number is the difference between 1/3 and .3333334.

Comment: @Benp404: It's not a matter of what you're "allowed" to do, but about how the word "polynomial" is used. You can use negative exponents in your expressions all you want, but the result is not _called_ a polynomial. That's a useful usage of the words because expressions without negative exponents (that is, polynomials) have useful properties that may be lost when you use negative exponents. For example, the value of a polynomial on a bounded interval is bounded, which is not true for your function.

Comment: $1/3$ and $0.3333334=\frac{3333334}{10000000}$ are both rational numbers, by the way.

Comment: Well I will have to go back and look up irrational and rational numbers.  I really was wondering how in the world do I prove $\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$ is or is not a polynomial?  Seems like this discussion includes ideas that I have yet to learn.

Comment: Maybe it is because $x^2$ in the numerator is not a polynomial that the whole equation is not a polynomial?

Comment: @Benp404 Suppose $\frac{x^2}{x^2-1} = P(x)$ for some polynomial $P$ of degree $n = \deg P$. Then $x^2=(x^2-1)P(x)$ and equating the degrees on the two sides $2 = 2 + n$.

Comment: Series $(x-1)^{-1}/2+3(x-1)^0/4+(x-1)^1/8-(x-1)^2/16+(x-1)^3/32-(x-1)^4/64+(x-1)^5/128+...$ converges to $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2-1}$ for real $x\in 0...2$ exept $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

No. A polynomial is a function of the form $a_n x^n + a_{n - 1} x^{n - 1} + \dotsb + a_0$. No algebraic coaxing will put $x^2 / (x^2 - 1)$ into that form.

Another way to see this is that a polynomial function is everywhere finite (continuous), while your function fails that, it isn't defined at $x = \pm 1$ (there it tends to $\infty$)